# .Net cors policy issue

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-web-api, mozilla, incognito-mode

I have a web project: .Net core API as a backend and React app as a frontend and everything is working fine with every browser except Mozilla private tab. When I run my react app in Mozilla private window this error occurs:

*Cross-Origin Request Blocked: ... Reason: CORS request did not succeed*

but if my cors policy is not correct how can other browsers connect my backend without any problem? (p.s Mozilla normal tab works fine as well)

Question: what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lot of same question :)
I'm facing same problem now.

After hundreds attempts i have semi-solition:

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddCors();
  //some other code here...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  //some code...
  app.UseRouting();

  app.UseCors(x => x
              .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowCredentials()
              .Build());   

 app.UseAuthorization();
 //other code
}
```

In react application:

```
export const loginUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'user/loginUser',
   async function(loginCredentials, {rejectWithValue}) {      
   try {                
       const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:5001/usr/loginuser`, {                
             method: 'POST',                
             headers: {                                                                          
                 'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                 'Accept': 'text/plain',
             },
             body: JSON.stringify({loginCredentials})
         });
           
         if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Server Error!');
        }

//other code
```

With this code i have situation when most of request are failed (seems like 'fetch canceled' in browser) but about 30% request are successfully. That's why i called it "semi"-solution.

Have no idea what's happening, because failed and normal requests are identical (headers and body).